# Js Value of delta equal 0 always

Tags: javascript, html, dom, var

Hello guys so im new to js and i'm trying to make a simple programme that caculate delta but the problem is that i always the value of delta 0 but when i set a static value to delta like an int it show the value correct where is the probleme and thanks

```
var first = document.getElementById("Cofession1"),
second = document.getElementById("Cofession2"),
third = document.getElementById("Cofession3"),
displayMessage = document.getElementById("solution"),
a = first.value,
b = second.value,
c = third.value,
btnClick = document.getElementById("calculateButton");
btnClick.onclick = function () {
var delta = b*5;
displayMessage.innerHTML = "delta = " + delta;
}
```

and this is the html

```
<input type="text" name="" id="Cofession1" placeholder="The value of a">
<input type="text" name="" id="Cofession2" placeholder="The value of b">
<input type="text" name="" id="Cofession3" placeholder="The value of c">
<button id="calculateButton">Calculate</button>
<div id="solution"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values of `a`, `b`, and `c` do not update automatically: you will need to assign them within the onclick method so that they reflect the value at the time the button is clicked. Otherwise they will always be an empty string since they are only evaluated at runtime.

Also, I do not recommend assigning directly to `onclick`, but use the more modern `addEventListener` instead.

```js
var first = document.getElementById("Cofession1");
var second = document.getElementById("Cofession2");
var third = document.getElementById("Cofession3");
var displayMessage = document.getElementById("solution");

btnClick = document.getElementById("calculateButton");
btnClick.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Assign values in the event handler
  var a = first.value;
  var b = second.value;
  var c = third.value;
  var delta = b * 5;
  displayMessage.innerHTML = "delta = " + delta;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" id="Cofession1" placeholder="The value of a">
<input type="text" name="" id="Cofession2" placeholder="The value of b">
<input type="text" name="" id="Cofession3" placeholder="The value of c">
<button id="calculateButton">Calculate</button>
<div id="solution"></div>
```